# how to substract two value on the column and show in another column mysql

Tags: php, mysql

am new to php and mysql so please dont downvote  my question. i have database that takes input from html form and i need one column named KIASI_KILICHOBAKI to be inserted automatically the substraction of two column named KIASI_ALICHOUZIWA - KIASI_ALICHOTOA. these are my codes:

```
$KIASI_ALICHOUZIWA =    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['KIASI_ALICHOUZIWA']);
$KIASI_ALICHOTOA = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['KIASI_ALICHOTOA']);

// Attempt insert query execution 

$sql = ("INSERT INTO taarifa (TAREHE,JINA_LA_KWANZA, JINA_LA_MWISHO,     NAMBA_YA_SIMU, SHINGO, BEGA, KIFUA, TUMBO, UPANA_WA_MKONO, UREFU_WA_MKONO,  HIPS_YA_KOTI, CHINI_UPANA_MKONO, HIPS_SURUALI, PAJA, KIUNO, GOTI,  UREFU_WA_SURUALI,CHINI_UPANA_SURUALI, ROUND_SURUALI, UREFU_WA_KIZIBAO, NAFASI_YA_KIZIBAO, HIPS_YA_KIZIBAO, UREFU_WA_MKONO_KIZIBAO , ROUND_YA_MKONO_KIZIBAO, KIASI_ALICHOUZIWA, KIASI_ALICHOTOA, KIASI_KILICHOBAKI) VALUES ('$TAREHE', '$JINA_LA_KWANZA', '$JINA_LA_MWISHO',  '$NAMBA_YA_SIMU', '$SHINGO', '$BEGA', '$KIFUA', '$TUMBO', '$UPANA_WA_MKONO','$UREFU_WA_MKONO','$KOTI', '$CHINI_UPANA_MKONO', '$SURUALI', '$PAJA', '$KIUNO', '$GOTI' ,'$UREFU_WA_SURUALI',  '$CHINI_UPANA_SURUALI', '$ROUND_SURUALI', '$UREFU_WA_KIZIBAO' , '$NAFASI_YA_KIZIBAO', '$HIPS_YA_KIZIBAO' , '$UREFU_WA_MKONO_KIZIBAO' ,'$ROUND_YA_MKONO_KIZIBAO' , '$KIASI_ALICHOUZIWA' , '$KIASI_ALICHOTOA' , '$KIASI_KILICHOBAKI')");
if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/myindex.php');
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not be able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
}

// Close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not created the $KIASI_KILICHOBAKI variable to save the answer. Add the following code before insert query

```
$KIASI_KILICHOBAKI = $KIASI_ALICHOUZIWA - $KIASI_ALICHOTOA;
```